# Java Script not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, html

I am using windows.scrollTo function to scroll to the top of the page in my HTML file . It works fine  in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 10. can anyone help ? !
 the code for the function is as follows :

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    function myFunction()
    {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine without the type attributes on script: http://jsfiddle.net/fka4a/

Comment: @Getz: It also works with it [**http://jsfiddle.net/8FT8F/**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FT8F/), specially in IE. IE uses JScript since IE3 and is Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript.

Comment: I just came across a post mentioning issues in the past with IE and they worked around it by using `setTimeout(‘window.scrollTo(0, 0)’,1);` While the fiddle I linked works firn in my IE11 I wonder if IE10 still suffered from past issues with scrollTo.

Comment: Another resource I came across but not sure it might have to do with hits was a [**jQuery Bug**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12343) which notes issues in IE10: `In Internet Explorer 10 event.pageX and event.pageY both have incorrect values: Instead of returning the mouse position relative to the document's Left/Top, the values returned are relative to the IE10 viewport's Left/Top.` Maybe that has something to do with it. In the comments is a lot of info on this and a IE10 patch which apparently fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `type="text/javascript"` instead of `type="text/jscript"`. Then your code should work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It would be very surprising if `text/jscript` would not work in IE, given that JScript is Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript used in IE since IE3. If anything `text/jscript` should only work in IE and not other browsers and in the past that was the case. Anyway, [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FT8F/) using `text/jscript` works fine in IE and chrome. To ensure the browsers are not just ignoring the MimeType as it is non-standard, changing it to `text/abc` will make the code stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `type` attribute and you should do fine. You are specifying a wrong type. It should be `text/javascript`

Javascript has sort of become a standard, that there is no need of `type` attribute.

You got away with other browsers, because, I think they are permissive. But IE is very picky about things.

Comment: IE is not picky in this regard. `text/jscript` works in IE. JScript is what Microsoft call JavaScript and is Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript used in IE. [**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FT8F/) using `text/jscript` works fine in IE and Chrome.